# Get global and assign value at same time

Tags: php, global-variables

Is this valid?

```
global $var = "New value";
```

I've seen it only in separate lines and i wondered if this is possible.

Comment: why dont you test it? it would take less time to do that than to ask

Comment: The $GLOBALS array can be used instead:

Comment: The reasy why i asked is because there may be some version requirements like with the ternary-operator-shorthand. Or it is simply not good style to write it like that ... I haven't found any information on that topic. Sure i could test it but the only thing that i know then is if it throws an error in my php version.

Comment: global keyword  expect only declaring the variable, you can not define the variable with global keyword in a single line, if required use $GLOBALS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid. This will treated as Parsing Error. 'global' keyword can't be used in that way. But this may be similar to your code that is valid in PHP.

```
$GLOBALS['var'] = 'New value';
```

Answer (score 1):

No You can't. It will give you syntax error saying unexpected '='.
Correct way is :

```
global $var;
$var = "New Value";
echo $var;
```